# Standardization, Oversampling and Evaluation

Tags: machine-learning

Please help me to understand which of the following is correct and why.

1. `X_train`, `X_test` : Split the training set into training and test sets
2. `X_train_std` : Standardize `X_train`
3. `X_train_res` : Oversample `X_train_std`
4. `model.fit` : Train the model using `X_train_res`
5. `X_test_std` : Standardize `X_test` using the parameters calculated in 2)
6. `model.evaluate` : Evaluate the model using `X_test_std`

Or:

1. `X_train`, `X_test` : Split the training set into training and test sets
2. `X_train_std` : Standardize `X_train`
3. `X_train_res` : Oversample `X_train_std`
4. `X_train_res_std` : Standardize `X_train_res`
5. `model.fit` : Train the model using `X_train_res_std`
6. `X_test_std` : Standardize `X_test` using the parameters calculated in 4)
7. `model.evaluate` : Evaluate the model using `X_test_std`

Answer (score 1):

Let's discuss the second variant:

If a standardization is considered as a function f(data) and the second standardization after oversampling is considered as a function g(f(data)), then you should use the same transformation for your test data. However, in the second option you just implement the function g(data) without transformation the data using function f().

Therefor, it seems to me, that the first variant is better. Moreover, it is enough to standardize data just once, so the first option is ok.

Comment: Thanks! In the first case the data used to train the model (X_train_res) is not standardized. So, why should we standardize X_test using the parameters found by standardizing X_train?

Comment: Data is standardized (2) and then oversampled (3) in the first case, as I can see. So, you train standardized data.